# How to count multiple things in 1 column

Tags: sql

I have this one table `empname`, `age`, and `gender`

```
     empname   age    gender
     Nana      24       F
     Jillian   28       M
     Sally     29       F
     David     30       M
     Mike      35       M
     Daisy     37       F
```

and the question is how do i count the gender who is female<30 years old, female>30, male<30 and male>30 from  table called `employee`

```
     female<30  female>30  male<30  male>30
         2          1         1        2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be using multiple sub-queries:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE gender = F AND age<30) AS 'Female Below 30',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE gender = F AND age>=30) AS 'Female Above 30',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE gender = M AND age<30) AS 'Male Below 30',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE gender = M AND age>=30) AS 'Male Above 30'
```

I think using PIVOT is better for such cases:

```
SELECT  [FB30],
        [FA30],
        [MB30],
        [MA30]
FROM    (
            SELECT  empname, 
                    gender + CASE WHEN age<30 THEN 'B30' ELSE 'A30' END AS SexAge 
            FROM    Employee
        ) AS SourceTable
        PIVOT
        (
            COUNT(empname)
            FOR SexAge IN ([FB30],[FA30],[MB30],[MA30])
        ) AS PivotTable;
```

Check out this **[SQL SERVER Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68eb1/2)**

After a bit of search (I am not into Oracle...) i ended up with this for the PIVOT:

```
WITH
   T
AS
(
    SELECT "empname" ,
           "gender" || CASE WHEN "age"<30 THEN 'B30' ELSE 'A30' END AS "SexAge"
    FROM  Employee
)
SELECT
   SUM(FB30) AS FB30,SUM(FA30) AS FA30,SUM(MB30) AS MB30,SUM(MA30) AS MA30
FROM
   T
PIVOT
(
   COUNT(*)
   FOR
      ("SexAge")
   IN
      ('FB30' AS FB30,'FA30' AS FA30,'MB30' AS MB30,'MA30' AS MA30)
);
```

[**Oracle PIVOT Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ebda/30)

And since you asked for a `DECODE` example:

```
WITH
   T
AS
(
    SELECT "empname" ,
           "gender" || DECODE(TRUNC("age"/30),0,'B30','A30') AS "SexAge"
    FROM  Employee
)
SELECT
   SUM(FB30) AS FB30,SUM(FA30) AS FA30,SUM(MB30) AS MB30,SUM(MA30) AS MA30
FROM
   T
PIVOT
(
   COUNT(*)
   FOR
      ("SexAge")
   IN
      ('FB30' AS FB30,'FA30' AS FA30,'MB30' AS MB30,'MA30' AS MA30)
);
```

[**Oracle DECODE PIVOT Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ebda/32)

Comment: this one working fine but i need to put distinct so the data won't duplicate

Comment: Where would you want the `Distinct`?

Comment: never mind that. can we use decode for the solution?

Comment: Are you in `Oracle`? Do you want to use `DECODE` instead of the case?

Comment: yes i'm in `Oracle` and i want to find other ways to get the result

Comment: I got you some more samples.

Comment: well, i admit i do not work with `Oracle`, so i just modified some samples i found on Google. :-)

Comment: i dont really understand about how pivot works and i tried it n it didnt work

Comment: Did you check the demos? What Oracle version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can query like this:

```
select
  count(case when gender='F' and age >= 30 then 1 end) "Female>=30",
  count(case when gender='F' and age < 30 then 1 end) "Female<30",
  count(case when gender='M' and age >= 30 then 1 end) "Male>=30",
  count(case when gender='M' and age < 30 then 1 end) "Male>30"
from ...
```

You can read the table **only once** to get the result what you want. This can be great difference when the table is large.

Comment: why do you need to put 1? if i put 0 its working too

Comment: You can put any value except `null`. `count` function count not null values.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select
    sum(case when gender='F' and age<30 then 1 end) [female<30],
    sum(case when gender='F' and age>=30 then 1 end) [female>30],
    sum(case when gender='M' and age<30 then 1 end) [male<30],
    sum(case when gender='M' and age>=30 then 1 end) [male>30]
from
    tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE
               WHEN gender = "F" and age < 30
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
        END ) AS female_lt_30
,
        SUM(CASE
               WHEN gender = "F" and age >= 30
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
        END ) AS female_ge_30
,
        SUM(CASE
               WHEN gender = "M" and age < 30
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
        END ) AS male_lt_30
,
        SUM(CASE
               WHEN gender = "M" and age >= 30
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
        END ) AS female_ge_30

FROM the_table;
```